# XAML data.binding - how can I bind properties in my method to the longitude/latitude in my view?

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm using GeoLocator to find out my position. This is the method:

```
private async void GetCurrentLocation()
{
    Geolocator locationFinder = new Geolocator
    {
        DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50,
        DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default
    };

    try
    {
        Geoposition currentLocation = await  locationFinder.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        String longitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
        String latitude = currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
        MyTextBlock.Text = "Long: " + longitude + "Lat: " + latitude;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        MyTextBlock.Text = "some message";
    }
}
```

Now, I'm my view I have this code (here with hard-coded values that I would like to replace with longitude/latitude from the above method).

```
<bm:Map ZoomLevel="7.5" Credentials="my key" x:Name="myMap">
    <bm:Map.Center>
        <bm:Location Latitude="48" Longitude="-122.580489" />
    </bm:Map.Center>
</bm:Map>
```

I'm very new to this kind of developing and would like to know how I can bind the properties in the method to the long/lat in my view. Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with ViewModels?  The concept is a ViewModel will expose the string GeoLocation properites and expose them to be bound to the view.  Then to get the view to to see the changes, an event is needed to be fired (INotifyPropertyChanged).  It's pretty complex to describe here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require some sort of object (usually called a ViewModel) from which your `Map` control would get its `DataContext`. (DataContext moves down the visual tree, from parent to child, unless explicitly set on any child control.) The ViewModel exposes information you'd like the view (your Window/other visible control) to visually represent somehow to the user.

Note that one of the crucial components of ViewModels in the MVVM style for WPF is that it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This interface allows an object to signal to the UI that the a value which is bound in the above fashion has changed, and the UI should be updated to reflect that.

Here's a really simple implementation of a ViewModel for your purposes:

```
// uses System.ComponentModel
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double longitude;
    public double Longitude
    { 
        get { return longitude; }
        set
        {
            longitude = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Longitude");
        }
    } 

    private double latitude;
    public double Latitude
    { 
        get { return latitude; }
        set
        {
            latitude = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Latitude");
        }
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This exposes a Longitude property and a Latitude property which you can use for binding in your XAML. If you're going to do true MVVM, those properties should probably be contained within a model object, and the ViewModel should in turn expose a collection of model objects to the View. As it stands, this is basically as simple an example as possible.

In general, you'd just use a simple binding to connect a control's property to your ViewModel's property, like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Longitude}" />
```

where the `TextBlock`'s DataContext had been set to an instance of YourViewModel.

However, it looks like the Bing `Map` object isn't a FrameworkElement, so it doesn't have a DataContext property, and binding is a little more complicated because it needs `StaticResource`s. I don't really have the capacity to test out the Bing maps API, but this link on [binding to non-FrameworkElements](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/devin_rader/archive/2011/04/29/binding-to-properties-of-non-frameworkelements.aspx) should help.

Comment: Very good answer! Im coming from an MVC-background so i am familiar with the concept of viewmodels. However, I connot see where in the code the properties in the view-model gets the values from the method? Should I create an instande om my view-model inside the method?

Comment: And what is "YourControl" in this scenario? Is it BM frpm the XAML?

Comment: @user2915962 The way it works is that, when `DataContext` is set on a control (`YourControl` in this case), any binding on that control and *any* of its children looks to the object you set as the DataContext. So for your `Map` control, you could either set the whole `Window` (or `UserControl`, depending on your platform)'s DataContext to an instance of `YourViewModel`, or you could just set the `Map`'s DataContext to the ViewModel. Either way, when you set a property of the Map to, say, `{Binding Longitude}`, it looks within the object set as its DataContext for a property with that name.

Comment: @user2915962 How high up in your visual tree you set the DataContext depends entirely on what function you want any given ViewModel to encapsulate - for some purposes, it's perfectly feasible to have the DataContext of your entire visible application set to a single ViewModel implementation, whereas in others you'll want to restrict your concerns and create a bunch of different ViewModel implementation and assign an instance of each to a *portion* of your application.

Comment: I really appreciate that you are trying to help me but i do not understand. Are you telling me that i now have a controller named MAP that I can set my datacontext to? Like this:
Map.DataContext = new ViewModel?

If so, where does this code go? Thank you!

Comment: @user2915962 Oh, no, I mean your `<bm:Map>` object within the XAML. `DataContext` is generally set on UI objects. You'd want to set the DataContext of your `bm:Map` control, from the XAML you posted in your question, to an instance of `YourViewModel`. (This would mean you'd have to provide an x:Name property to the control, if you wanted to set its DataContext in code-behind.)

Comment: @user2915962 It's also possible there's a linguistic error here - in WPF, "control" generally means an object placed on the UI, not the "controller" sense of MVC.

Comment: Ok, i am actually creating an win 8 store app. Maybe that changes stuff as well. Im trying to give bm:map an x:Name but keep getting an error. ""Duplicate name attribute 'x:name'. This is very diffrent from what i am used to.

Comment: @user2915962 Ah, my mistake! I somehow glazed over the fact that you'd already included an x:Name. I've updated the code.

Comment: Cant understand how this works. I have the view-model with the two properties. Somwhere in my MainPage.xaml.cs I shuld write:
myMap.DataContext = new YourViewModel();

This will somehow asign  the two poperties in the VW with the reulting values from the mthod? I must be missing something here? 
I mean, if I create an instance of my VM like this it will be empty?

Comment: In your class, above `InitializeComponent()`, write either `this.DataContext = new YourViewModel()` or `myMap.DataContext = new YourViewModel()`, depending on whether you want to the `YourViewModel` as the DataContext for the whole page or just to the map.

Comment: when using: myMap.DataContext = new YourViewModel i get a null-exception.
When using this.datacontect = new YourViewModel() I do not get a null exception but the this.DataContext does never get any values? How does my VM know what values I am trying to give it?

Comment: Here is the error when using myMap.Datacontext = new YourViewModel()
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myapp.Windows.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The nullref-problem got solved when i moved myMap.DataContext = new YourViewModel beneath the initializeComponent. I would imagine that when after my method has run (the metod that gets the long/lat), these values should be assigned to the properties in the vm? I cant see this happen anywhere?

Comment: @user2915962 Hold on - it looks like the `Map` object isn't a FrameworkElement, so this is a little more difficult. Also, you'll have to assign the values yourself - I haven't initialized anything in the ViewModel implementation. As I said, this is as simple as it gets.

Comment: @user2915962 I'll see if I can find anything better, but to be honest, this is two separate questions: 1. "How do I bind in XAML" and 2. "How do I bind the Bing Map object". I can't answer #2, and you're probably better off asking a separate question.